# What is the limit of session.open and how to close the session in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Is there a limit to the number of `sessions.open` that can be executed by Apache IoTDB? If the `session` is opened and did not manually close, will it be closed automatically after a period of time? Or what conditions should I pay attention to manually close the `session` to save resources?

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no restrictions on the number of `session` using `session pool` in Apache IoTDB. If you do not release the tasks manually, the resources will continually be used. If you are executing query operations, then the result sets must be manually checked, but you do not have to manually check the results for insertion operations.